# Why does Keras crash when I feed a 1D list as input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression

I'm just getting started with Keras so I thought I'd try to make the simplest regression problems I can think of, as a sort of Hello World.

I'm trying to train a model that outputs the double of the input. I imagine that a network with two nodes (1 input 1 output) with no activation function should do the trick. The weight should simply converge to 2.

This is my code:

```
layers = keras.layers

# Feed forward structure
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01),
              loss='mae',
              metrics=['mae'])


train_data = np.asarray([x for x in range(100)])
train_labels = np.asarray([x * 2 for x in train_data])


model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

However, when I feed it a 1D numpy array it crashes with the following error:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

If I then add redundant parenthesis to `train_data` it compiles (without converging):

```
train_data = np.asarray([[x for x in range(100)]])

Epoch 50/50

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 705us/step - loss: 50.0463 - mean_absolute_error: 50.0463
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are giving the model a single number, each input sample must have a shape of `(1,)`. Therefore, all the 100 input samples would have a shape of `(100,1)`. Therefore, you need to make the shapes of your input data and the labels consistent with what is expected:

```
train_data = train_data.reshape(100,1)  # 100 samples of shape 1

# you may not need to do the following necessarily
train_labels = train_labels.reshape(100,1)  # 100 labels of shape 1

# alternative way using np.expand_dims
train_data = np.expand_dims(train_data, axis=-1)
```

Side notes:

1. Your model has two `Dense` layers. With the description you provided, I think you just want a model with one Dense layer which has one unit (i.e. remove one of the Dense layers).
2. When you put your data in another list, like this:

   ```
   train_data = np.asarray([[x for x in range(100)]])
   ```

   it would become a 2D array of shape `(1,100)` which means **one** sample of shape `(100,)` which is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense! I'll test it out asap. By the way, your name is awesome, it confused me for a second.

Comment: I'm not sure why I should remove a layer, woudn't that leave me with a single node and no connections/weights? Or is there already an extra layer the size of the input by default?

Comment: @AlexP. When you write `Dense(1)` it means there is a neuron which is connected to some other neuron(s) and therefore has some weights associated with it. In Keras there is always an input layer, either explicitly created by you using [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), or implicitly created by Keras when using Sequential API. And by the way, thanks for your kind words about my username!